# Send model id in Put Body not in url

Tags: rest, restful-url

As we know the format of PUT method in Restful should be something like this:

> /api/user/{id}

and the PUT body
But is it OK if I just call `/api/user` and I send the `{id}` inside the PUT body like this: `{"id": "1", "name": "myname"}`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I PUT without an ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391191/can-i-put-without-an-id)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer of the proposed duplicate is not correct though