# "Restful" solution to accept a list of objects

Tags: rest

I'm looking at a scenario where we have one parent `resource` (real name removed to protect the innocent). As a child object, we have a list of `prices` organized by effectiveDate.

```
Preexisting CRUD on api/resource
New POST on api/resource/{code}/someRelationship/{relId}/prices
```

A few months ago we created the POST `prices` endpoint. It takes a list of `price` objects. Currently this appends new `prices` to a pre-existing list in the database. There's no handling of duplicates when we consume these `prices` other than the last in wins if the effectiveDates are the same.  We did not expose an id and just wanted to associate some `prices` to the parent `resource` object given someRelationship.

```
{
  "prices": [
    {
      "price": 0,
      "effectiveDateTime": "2020-02-14T18:30:33.710Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Life went on. Things got more complicated.  We ran into a situation where something might change in the source of truth system where the effectiveDate shifts. If this happens, we believe that we will incorrectly leave behind remnant `prices` on the system that we're synchronizing to. The new ones will get pushed over, but there will be old `prices` that are no longer correct. It seems drastically easier to just take whatever the system we're synchronizing from gives us because it's the source of truth for `prices`.

Options:

1. Lean into `POST api/resource/{code}/someRelationship/{relId}/prices`

   - Can we continue to treat the `prices` object as a list belonging to the parent `resource` rather than a first class, restful object?
   - Change the POST logic to wipe out the old `prices`, and save the new ones that were broadcast by the calling system since it knows about ALL the `prices` and can save them in one call.
   - We can argue if it should be named PUT or POST. Sounds like POST to me.
   - I'm told this breaks all that is holy with restful conventions.
   - Would have to update api docs to communicate this functionality because we broke the restful conventions.
2. promote the `prices` object to a first class, restful object of the api.

   - But this means we'll have to create full CRUD endpoints exposing the id

     - or use the effectiveDateTime as the id which seems weird
   - Workflow for the caller to juggle full CRUD of `prices`

     - `GET /api/resource/{code}/someRelationship/{relId}/prices`

       - to get a list to know what changes to push over
     - `price` in both sides with the same value and effectiveDate? Do nothing.
     - `POST /api/resource/{code}/someRelationship/{relId}/prices`

       - `price` missing from side to be synchronized? POST it one by one? Or can we add it to a list and POST the list? what if we have 100 prices? 100 APIs calls?
     - `PUT /api/resource/{code}/someRelationship/{relId}/prices/{id}`

       - `price` wrong from side to be synchronized? PUT it one by one.
     - `DELETE /api/resource/{code}/someRelationship/{relId}/prices/{id}`

       - `price` in the side to be synchronized but missing in the source of truth? Delete it one by one.
   - comparison logic could get more confusing if we continue to add fields to what a `price` is (more than price and effectiveDate)
   - Example: Multiply by 12 months times a few parent `resources`. 12 months * 100 `price` API calls * 5 `resources` = 6000 calls?

Comment: How about just adding a new PUT endpoint that replaces an old list with a new one? Then the existing POST endpoint and the `prices` resource don't have to change.

Comment: I thought you needed an id when PUTing. In this case we would not have one. Are you suggesting to call `PUT /api/resource/{code}/someRelationship/{relId}/prices` without an id just taking the list of prices? EDIT: This is interesting... https://stackoverflow.com/a/43393302/202963

Comment: Resources in ReST are identified by URIs. If you have a (unique) URI to point to, then you have an ID.