# Should the resource ID be put in URL of PUT and PATCH requests?

Tags: rest, patch, put

Should PUT's and PATCH's URL contains ID or could it be put inside the body?

```
PUT /person/UUID {"name": "Jimmy"}
```

OR

```
PUT /person/{"UUID":1, "name": "Jimmy"}
```

( the same for the PATCH)
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `PUT` is defined as *Replace the current document found at the URI location with the one provided in the payload* sending a `PUT` request to `/person` should probably lead to a removal of any person managed by that particular endpoint, in case that URI represents a collection of persons.

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391191/can-i-put-without-an-id/43393302#43393302) one might use a URI without some special entity identifier in case this is an all purpose container. Think of a clipboard where you can copy some data to to later on retrieve it to paste it somewhere else. In such a case the identifier is implicitly given by the URI itself, as after all URI stands for *unique resource identifier*

Note that a URI as a whole identifies a resource and does not necessarily imply some form of parent-child structure. A client especially should not attempt to extract knowledge from an URI at all.

In regards to `PATCH` it depends. Usually one should use a media-type that is intended for patching such as [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) or [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396).

The former representation defines certain fields that state that a field should be added, removed or replaced with a given value in a notation like the one listed below:

```
   PATCH /my/data HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.org
   Content-Length: 326
   Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
   If-Match: "abc123"

   [
     { "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "foo" },
     { "op": "remove", "path": "/a/b/c" },
     { "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] },
     { "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": 42 },
     { "op": "move", "from": "/a/b/c", "path": "/a/b/d" },
     { "op": "copy", "from": "/a/b/d", "path": "/a/b/e" }
   ]
```

JSON Merge Patch however works differently. It defines some default rules that instruct a server on how to apply the changes to the target document. A document like below i.e. will either add or update field *a*  to have value *z*  afterwards  while the property *f*  of *c*'s object has to be deleted. All the other remaining properties of that resource remain as they are.

```
   PATCH /target HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.org
   Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

   {
     "a":"z",
     "c": {
       "f": null
     }
   }
```

Both of these media-types could be used to send a request directly to the "collection"-resource as both can target sub-elements by definition. However, in terms of caching I'd try to avoid it.

Caching in HTTP works de facto on the URI of the resource. Any unsafe operation performed on that URI leads to the cache invalidating a stored representation for that target. I.e. if you previously invoked `GET /person/1` and now perform a `PUT` or `PATCH`, which both are unsafe operations, on `/person` the data might get updated, though a client requesting `GET /person/1` afterwards may still retrieve the cached response via the cache as it is unaware of any changes done to that resource.